# How to disable hidden search of table row in table sorter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where say there are 20 rows. I have a button which hides 10 rows from these 20. I have used jquery with a class to hide and show these 10 records. Now when i search for example - "A" i get the search results from all the 20 rows. Ideally it should search only those visible records. I cant find this in any documentation. Has any one landed with the same problem. Please help me out with this.

```
 $("#mytableid").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: false },
            5: { sorter: false },
            //6: { sorter: false },
            7: { sorter: false },
            8: { sorter: false }
        },
        // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
        widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],

        ignoreCase: false,

        widgetOptions: {
            filter_columnFilters: true,
            filter_hideFilters: false,
            filter_searchDelay: 300,
            //filter_liveSearch: true,
            filter_ignoreCase: true
        }
    });
```

The show hide logic is below

```
$("tr td span.status-canceled").closest("tr").show();
$("tr td span.status-canceled").closest("tr").hide();
```

The table in HTML

```
<table>
<tr style="display:none">
<td>some data 1</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none">
<td>some data 2</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none">
<td>some data 3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none">
<td>some data 4</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<tr>
<td>some data 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>some data 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add your script to the question, or a Jsfiddle. We cannot/will not predict your code.

Comment: Added the code in my question. i hope its more clearer to you now.

Answer (score 0):

use **[visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector

```
$( "tr:visible" ).length;
```

do like this

```
$( "tr:visible" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).text();  // get text
});
```

Comment: Above code would give me only tr that are visible. The table sorter plug-in needs the entire table object. i've added the code in my question. i hope it makes the question more clear.

Comment: thanks for all your effort. But the table sorter plugin here needs the entire table object. I have tried this already. The selector gives out the rows that are visible. I need the entire table object. The one which we get using $("#mytableid"). If here i can get the table object with only visbile table rows in it, then that would work. I hope my question is clear to you. If not let me know what you haven't understood.

Comment: @Raza So you need the table object which has visible rows in it.. Right..?

Comment: yes i hope that would do the trick. I was looking at the documentation of tablesorter plug-in and nowhere this is mentioned. I was looking more for an attribute of tablesorter plug-in. But the table object might do the trick.